# Create a Corelocation Model Class

Tags: ios, swift, cllocation

I am using Corelocation in several views for which I use the following code :

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ModelCL: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

let LocationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //CoreLocation
    self.LocationManager.delegate = self
    self.LocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.LocationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.LocationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location!, completionHandler: {
        (placemarks, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            print("Error")
        }

        if let pm = placemarks?.first {
            self.displayLocationInfo(pm)
        }
        else {
            print("Error : data error")
        }

    })
}

func displayLocationInfo (placemark: CLPlacemark) {

    self.LocationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    print(placemark.subThoroughfare)
    print(placemark.thoroughfare)
    print(placemark.locality)
    print(placemark.postalCode)
    print(placemark.subAdministrativeArea)
    print(placemark.administrativeArea)
    print(placemark.country)

}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
    print("Error :" + error.localizedDescription)
}
}
```

It works well on each view as I implemented it on each of them. Wouldn't it better to create only one Model Class with this code and call the administrative level needed on each view? I can't figure out how to call it on another view...

Comment: see this may be it help you https://gist.github.com/igroomgrim/ac1d46b5aea1173e6760

Comment: You are looking for the Singleton Pattern. Here is a tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/86477/introducing-ios-design-patterns-in-swift-part-1

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for, still don't understand how to call it on another class...

Comment: You can call it with : `ModelLC.LocationManager.startUpdating()`, since it's a singleton you can call every method in this class with :  `ModelLC.LocationManager.yourMethodHere()` . I also suggest you don't use capital letter for you singleton but something like: `let sharedInstance = CLLocationManager()` it's easier to remember that it is a singleton.